# Symlinks from same directory are not getting copied in installer generated by install4j

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j 7.0.2
I am having symlinks in source directory. These are required to run the application.
After adding the source directory in "Define Distribution Tree" and generating installer, symlinks are not present in installation directory.

Also if I try to include all files using *, it is also not supported.

Please suggest a solution to include symlinks.

Comment: What platform are you working on? (Unix (which one?), Linux (which one?), ...)

Answer (score 0):

The distribution tree does not collect symlinks or Unix file permissions, this would not work in a multi-platform way.

You can use "Create a symbolic link" actions in the installer to create symlinks.

---

**Update 2021-03-04**

Preserving symbolic links in the distribution tree on Linux and macOS has been added in install4j 9.

Comment: Distribution tree is having multiple symbolic links, so it is tedious to add multiple action to create symbolic links.
Also addition of some more symlinks in future is also one case.
Is there any other way to take care this?

Comment: You can tar your source directory, add the tar file to the distribution tree and use an "Extract tar file" action in the installer.

Comment: @IngoKegel If we use tar file with source directory contents , then when upgrading I am using "Execute previous uninstaller" and the files created by tar files are not uninstalled also I dont get any option to prevent overwriting some files as these files are present in distribution tree

Comment: Is the inclusion of symbolic links in installer supported in install4j 8/9 for linux platform ?

Comment: This has indeed been added in install4j 9. I'll update the answer.